# UI testing get text from uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm writting some UI Tests and I'm currently having a problem to match some text that is in a tableview cell.

So I want to test that a tableview has all the cases that it needs to have.

I tried it as follows:

```
if !app.staticTexts["sometext"].exists {
// FAIL
}
```

but this doens't work because it doesn't find the text and then I found something like this:

```
app.tables.cells.staticTexts["some text"].exists
```

and last but not least like this:

```
app.tables.cells.containingType(.StaticText, identifier: "some text")
```

But it seems that the is never finding the text and it is on the screen. 
Someone knows how to get the text out of a tableview cell?

Comment: I found the problem. I'm having 2 tableviews and app.tables is taking the first tableview not the second one. So I just need to switch to the second tableview somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the accessibilityIdentifier on both your UITableViews, then you will be able to choose the right table every time.

```
app.tables["myIdentifier"].cells.staticTexts["some text"]
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the same with KIF framework ??

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the KIF API.

Comment: For me, the text in cell is dynamic, I use `app.cells["myIdentifier"].staticTexts.element(boundBy: 1).label` to get the date string in cell.

Answer (score 2):

When the identifier for the cell is well defined - things will be in place. Try -

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let tablesQuery = app.tables
    XCTAssertTrue(tablesQuery.cells.containing(.staticText, identifier: "my identifier").staticTexts["Some Text"].exists,
                  "Failure: Something went wrong.")
```